# Published Git branch in Azure DevOps not showing in VS2013 or Git Command Line

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013, version-control, azure-devops

My co-worker has a local branch. He "publishes" it from VS Team Explorer. It shows up in Visual Studio Online's list of branches.

I am connected to the same TFS-Git system, logged in via VS, connected via Team Explorer, and yet when I view the list of branches I can clone from it is not there.

I finally resorted to using the command line to view all branches, but it doesn't even show up there. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

What am I missing? This is a serious problem for us.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I'm not certain what did it, but I can now see the branch in Team Explorer. My best guess is that it had to do with issuing a manual "fetch" of the "master" and "development" branches. I'm surprised that would be required to see remote branches. It's essentially like you have to fetch and cache the remote branch info, then issue another command (branch -r) to see what you cached. That may not be what happened, but it's my best guess. I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: What is your screenshot illustrating?  What should be there?  Did you create a new local branch that points to the remote branch?

Comment: The right side of the screenshot is showing Visual Studio Online's published branches and the left side is the Git command prompt with the "show all branches" command executed. Remote branches are in red, and the published one denoted by the arrow should be there in the list of remote branches, or at least it seems it should be. See my original post.

Comment: I'm trying to create a local branch from the remote one, but it doesn't show up as a branch I can clone, even though it's there in VSO and my co-worker has "published" it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Just to make sure, you have fetched the repo since that branch was added, correct?

Comment: **Fetch** did it for me and updated my branch list. Refreshing in the *Branches* view in Team Explorer did not work.

Answer (score 9):

You will need to first do a Pull to make sure you local repo is up to date with the changes. You then have the new origin\otherdudes branch pointers locally.

Then you can create a new branch in visual studio and select the origin\otherdudes branch as the server target.

This is just how git works and the same actions from the command line will also do the same thing. You always need to create a working copy of a published branch before you can edit it.